# Could not find Java jdk in a directory that has been renamed

Tags: 16.04, java, jdk, android-studio, npm

I am trying to built a React Native app using Ubuntu 16.04. When I try to run `npm run android` in the terminal I get this error `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /home/duong/git/Java/jdk1.8.0_144`

The weird thing is that I have renamed my "git" folder to "admin" a while ago, and I also have deleted the Java directory in there also. How come npm sees the folder and not me? So now I don't know where the Java jdk is in my system. How can I retrieve the Java folder and set it to default location?

Comment: Presumably you originally set `JAVA_HOME` to `/home/duong/git/Java/jdk1.8.0_144` in one of your shell initialization files (such as `~/.bashrc`) and forgot to change it when you renamed the directory?

Comment: Yeah so I edited the bashrc file to a new path. When I run 'echo $JAVA_HOME' I get the output '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle'. But when I typed just '$JAVA_HOME' I get this error instead.. 'bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: No such file or directory
'

Comment: Well `JAVA_HOME` won't be an executable file, it will be a directory - unfortunately I can't tell you where you installed it, you will need to figure that out yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ls /home/duong/git/Java/jdk1.8.0_144` Does that dir exist?

You say you renamed the "git" folder to "admin".

Try `ls /home/duong/admin/Java/jdk1.8.0_144` Does that dir exist?

Do you have Java installed from a .deb package from the repository?

Try

```
foo@bar:$ which java
/usr/bin/java
foo@bar:$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Oct 21  2016 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
foo@bar:$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Sep 15 19:03 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
foo@bar:$
```

The system wide install creates the many symlinks seen above. Following these will show you the directory in which java is installed. In the example directly above this is /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

When you find your java install directory, set that as JAVA_HOME

E.g.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/duong/admin/Java/jdk1.8.0_144
```

or whatever directory in which your java is installed.

Then run your `npm` command.